# Is there a way I can use angular-generator without yeoman?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

Basically what I want is a scaffolding tool (without bower and other stuff that it comes with) and controller, service/factory generators.

Yeoman is great but I was wondering if there's anything minimalist cli out there for angular.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if all you want is a base angular app structure, that is called a boilerplate. There are a few available:

- https://github.com/angular/angular-seed
- https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp
- https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app

However, you seem to also want a controller, service/factory generator. This will always require:

- some kind of task runner (like Grunt)
- or an IDE that supports templates.

Since you don't seem to like grunt (grunt IS AWESOME), these IDEs might help you...

- **[Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/)** supports template, you can find some [**here**](https://github.com/bkbonner/angularjs-eclipse-templates/)
- IntelliJ's [**PHPStorm**](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) or [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) have a feature called **[Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-templates.html)** which, IMHO, are far better than eclipse. You can find some **[premade templates here](https://github.com/angularjs-livetpls/angularjs-webstorm-livetpls)**, but is easy to roll your own, **[as explained in this tutorial](http://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/live-templates-for-angular-js-in-webstorm/)**.

Comment: Call me lazy but downloading boilerplate and copying them on the right folder feels so much hassle. And yes, grunt is awesome but gulp is awesomer :D. I've been looking at `slush` but I would run far, far away from Eclipse.

Comment: @shriek well, you can always create a template with the full boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a command line interface but not Yeoman's, you might want to have a look at the "Generation" section of [this collection](http://dancancro.com/comparison-of-angularjs-application-starters).  As of today, it has one option that uses Lineman and two that made their own CLI, but they use bower.  Anyway, if what you're looking for exists, it should be in there somewhere.